# How can I prevent focus changes on scroll/fling for a HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android, android-scrollview, horizontalscrollview

When an EditText or other focusable View exists inside of a `HorizontalScrollView` it gets focused when flinging.

Digging into source, you can see why:

```
    /**
     * Fling the scroll view
     *
     * @param velocityX The initial velocity in the X direction. Positive
     *                  numbers mean that the finger/cursor is moving down the screen,
     *                  which means we want to scroll towards the left.
     */
    public void fling(int velocityX) {
        if (getChildCount() > 0) {
            int width = getWidth() - mPaddingRight - mPaddingLeft;
            int right = getChildAt(0).getWidth();

            mScroller.fling(mScrollX, mScrollY, velocityX, 0, 0,
                    Math.max(0, right - width), 0, 0, width/2, 0);

            final boolean movingRight = velocityX > 0;

            View currentFocused = findFocus();
            View newFocused = findFocusableViewInMyBounds(movingRight,
                    mScroller.getFinalX(), currentFocused);

            if (newFocused == null) {
                newFocused = this;
            }

            if (newFocused != currentFocused) {
                newFocused.requestFocus(movingRight ? View.FOCUS_RIGHT : View.FOCUS_LEFT);
            }

            postInvalidateOnAnimation();
        }
    }
```

Some of the suggested workarounds for this involve using the following attributes:

```
   android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

This works well for some simple cases, but it can lead to odd behavior if your `HorizontalScrollView` is nested in another `ScrollView` (e.g the outer scroll view will jump to the container now being focused).

Also from experience trying this solution, it can require adding it to *every* parent container containing a focusable view (e.g. `EditText`). If you have any sort of complex focus logic going on, this all can get out of hand.

Are there any other workaround solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other solution to this is to subclass `HorizontalScrollView` and make the following modifications:

```
/**
 * Class which modifies default focus logic so that children aren't focused
 * when scrolling/flinging.
 */
class NoFocusHorizontalScrollView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : HorizontalScrollView(context, attrs) {

  private var flingCallInProgress: Boolean = false

  override fun onRequestFocusInDescendants(direction: Int, previouslyFocusedRect: Rect?): Boolean {
    return true
  }

  override fun fling(velocityX: Int) {
    // Mark that the fling is in progress before calling the fling logic. 
    // This should be fairly safe given we're on the UI thread.

    flingCallInProgress = true
    super.fling(velocityX)
    flingCallInProgress = false
  }

  override fun getFocusables(direction: Int): ArrayList<View> {
    // During a fling HSV will try to focus on a child. This helps prevents that behavior.

    return if (flingCallInProgress) {
      ArrayList(0)
    } else {
      super.getFocusables(direction)
    }
  }

}
```